# Opening 2 WebCams From The Same USB Cable

Tags: macos, image-processing, webcam

So i got this cool double `WebCam` that connect to the mac from a single usb cable.[image: b]

i can see that my mac recognized the cameras as i connect it. i write a little program from `XCODE` that stream cam video to `QTCaptureView` in to two QTCaptureViews left and right

```
                 [ left cam view ]    [ right cam view ]
```

before i post some code i would like to tell that if i choose one of the cams to be streamed and the face time camera also (for example it could be any other cam instead of the cam that connected to the same port) i get both streamed at the same time.
but if i choose both camera to be projected only one will work.
it could be something that is impossible on the hardware level?
i would really like to hear some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use "Video Capture Sources" filter from [GraphEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where you should see two capture ports that can be rendered simultaneously.

A more advanced solution is to use OpenCV as follows:

```
Mat Lframe,Rframe;
```

For multi-head camera, use:

```
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if(cap.grab())
    cap.retrieve(Lframe,0); cap.retrieve(Rframe,1);// get a new frame
```

For two stereo cameras:

```
VideoCapture capL(0),capR(1);
capL.grab();capR.grab();
capL.retrieve(Lframe); capR.retrieve(Rframe);// get a new frame
```

See [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) for more details.

Comment: are you sure its not something related to hubbing?

Comment: It depends on how the system can see them, if two different IDs have been assigned to the cameras then use the two stereo version. if single ID is assigned so computer sees a single camera (the outputs of both channels are sync, encoded and transmitted together) then multi-head version may work for you. You can check that easily through graphedit.

Comment: when i create 2 VideoCapture objects the app dont loaded. with one it works

Comment: @or azran, I suspect USB bandwidth allocating problem. not very sure if that is the cause though(usually the case for 2 seperate camera with individual usb cable each). But still, do give it a shot. Some methods to overcome that problem: 1)put a Sleep(ms) in between the lines of your capture line. 2)Use lower resolution which would reduce the bandwidth used by each camera. 3)Use MJPEG format(compressed frames). Should it work, let me know, so that I can post it as an answer(:

Comment: @or azran, can you give mire details on why assigning 2 VideoCapture objects is not working? Have you tried reteriving different channels? You may elliminate the limited bandwidth problem by setting width/height to lower resolution for both cameras.

Comment: @Basel the width / height not even executed so it should not be bother.